# Change BPM in real time with AVAudioEngine using Swift

Tags: swift, audio, buffer, avaudioengine

Hello I am trying to implement simple audio app using AVAudioEngine, which plays short wav audio files in a loop at some bpm, that can be changed in real time (by slider or something).

Current solution logic:

1. set bpm=60
2. create audioFile from sample.wav
3. calculate bufferSize: AVAudioFrameCount(audioFile.processingFormat.sampleRate * 60 / Double(bpm))
4. set bufferSize to audioBuffer
5. load file audioFile into audioBuffer.
6. schedule audioBuffer to play

This solution works, but the issue is - if I want to change bpm I need to recreate buffer with different bufferSize, so it will not be in real time, since I need to stop player and reschedule buffer with different bufferSize.

Any thoughts how it can be done ?
Thanks in advance !

Code (main part):

```
var bpm:Float = 30

let engine = AVAudioEngine()
var player = AVAudioPlayerNode()

var audioBuffer: AVAudioPCMBuffer?
var audioFile: AVAudioFile?

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    audioFile = loadfile(from: "sound.wav")
    audioBuffer = tickBuffer(audioFile: audioFile!)
    
    engine.attach(player)
    engine.connect(player, to: engine.mainMixerNode, format: audioFile?.processingFormat)
    do {
        engine.prepare()
        try engine.start()
    } catch {
        print(error)
    }
}

private func loadfile(from fileName: String) -> AVAudioFile? {
    let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: fileName, ofType: nil)!
    let url = URL(fileURLWithPath: path)
    do {
        let audioFile = try AVAudioFile(forReading: url)
        return audioFile
    } catch {
        print("Error loading buffer1 \(error)")
    }
    return nil
}

func tickBuffer(audioFile: AVAudioFile) -> AVAudioPCMBuffer {
    let periodLength = AVAudioFrameCount(audioFile.processingFormat.sampleRate * 60 / Double(bpm))
    let buffer = AVAudioPCMBuffer(pcmFormat: audioFile.processingFormat, frameCapacity: periodLength)!
    try! audioFile.read(into: buffer)
    buffer.frameLength = periodLength
    return buffer
}

func play() {
    player.scheduleBuffer(audioBuffer, at: nil, options: .loops, completionHandler: nil)
    player.play()
}

func stop() {
    player.stop()
}
```

Comment: `AVAudioUnitVarispeed` might be helpful: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfaudio/avaudiounitvarispeed

Comment: @sbooth Thanks for comment. Yes AVAudioUnitVarispeed has rate parameter, but it will also change octave, which is not what I am looking for.

Comment: `AVAudioUnitTimePitch` might be better for your use case.

Comment: So you want to loop a wav file back-to-back, and change the bpm, but not the pitch of the sound.  That would require pitch correction.  But there are simpler ways you could do it, if... Are you basically trying to create a metronome?